# Present continuous without a pronoun?

Tags: verbs, participles

I was looking at a post which said:

> "organo konsistanta el karnaj fibroj kaj servanta por movi la
>   diversajn partojn de la korpo"

I am a bit confused on why `konsistanta` was used instead of `konsistas` or even `konsistante`?

Would the same rule apply when we say things like "Holding to your word, Standing on your promises, loving you is easy, etc."

Comment: Hi rugxan, and welcome to [esperanto.SE]! What's the content of that "post"? Could it be that it wasn't intended as a complete sentence, but as, say, a definition of some medical term?

Comment: Ah, indeed, found it [by googling](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22organo%20konsistanta%20el%20karnaj%20fibroj%20kaj%20servanta%20por%20movi%20la%20diversajn%20partojn%20de%20la%20korpo%22). I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Re-reading the question, I'm a bit confused. The title says "without a pronoun", but the lack of that pronoun (Do you, by chance, mean the subject?) doesn't seem to be a topic of the body of the question. Or is it?

Comment: Let me try and explain this: I forgot what the word I was looking for but, apparently in grammatical terms it's called a gerund. For example, sentences like "Writing in English is hard" and "Before going to bed I drink some water" - how would "writing" and "going" be translated?

Comment: I think I found the source of this. When it’s presented like this I guess it’s less obvious that the phrase is meant to quoting from a dictionary definition. https://www.instagram.com/p/B5IiOkkK1Lg/?igshid=1k5rmslks3c5j

Comment: @rugxan In that case the gerund is used like an infinitive. English is confusing because it uses the gerund for two different things. In esperanto you would just use the infinitive (*skribi en la angla estas malfacile*). The gerund in your question is the other kind.

Answer (score 2):

## Why *konsistanta* instead of *konsistas*?

> organo konsistanta el karnaj fibroj kaj servanta por movi la diversajn partojn de la korpo

is [ReVo's definition of "muskol/o"](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/muskol.html). (Also reflected [here](http://www.simplavortaro.org/vorto/muskolo) in Simpla Vortaro.)

For dictionary definitions of words or terms, it's not unusual to not be complete sentences and to lack a conjugated verb. This is done in English dictionaries, too, see e.g. [wiktionary's entry for "muscle (Noun)"](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=muscle&oldid=54340685#Noun):

> 1. (uncountable) A contractile form of tissue which animals use to effect movement.
> 2. (countable) An organ composed of muscle tissue.
> 3. (uncountable, usually in the plural) A well-developed physique, in which the muscles are enlarged from exercise.
> 4. (uncountable, figuratively) Strength, force.
> 5. (uncountable, figuratively) Hired strongmen or bodyguards.

In English, it's implied that you can read the definitions like

> *<term>* can mean / is *<definition>*

e.g.

> "muscle" can mean a contractile form of tissue which animals use to effect movement.

Similarly, in Esperanto, you can read dictionary definitions like this as

> *<vorto>* povas signifi / estas *<difino>*

e.g.

> muskolo estas organo konsistanta el karnaj fibroj kaj servanta por movi la diversajn partojn de la korpo

## Why *konsistanta* instead of *konsistante*?

*-e* would make it an adverb. An adverb needs an adjective or verb that it applies to. Sometimes, that adverb or verb can be implied instead of explicitly mentioned, but here, I wouldn't even know what it could be.

You can read

> organo konsistanta el karnaj fibroj [...]

as

> organo, **kiu estas** konsistanta el karnaj fibroj [...]

though even without the relative sentence, *"konsistanta el karnaj fibroj"* and *"servanta por movi la diversajn partojn de la korpo"* grammatically take the roles of adjectives further describing *"organo"*, thus their main words (*konsistanta* and *servanta*) get the adjective ending *-a*. Remember that normal adjectives in Esperanto can be in front or after the term (usually a noun) they apply to, and having them in front is more common. When the role of an adjective is taken by a phrase consisting of several words, that phrase has to be put after the noun, though.

Actually, this is similar in English. We have:

> An organ composed of muscle tissue.

and not

> <strike>An organ composedly of muscle tissue.</strike>

## "present continuous"?

Note that "present continuous" is a term describing a tense of the English grammar and that it requires a conjugated form of the verb "to be".

The form of the verbs-turned-into-adjectives with the *-ant-* suffix and the *-a* adjective word ending is called the active [participle](https://lernu.net/en/gramatiko/participoj) present. While participles in Esperanto can be used to form tenses analogous to (but much less commonly used than) those in English, they can also be used as adjectives, and that seems to be the case here.

Comment: So, if it wasn't intended as a complete sentence what verb ending should one use?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. "What verb ending should one use" _for what_? In a phrase that isn't a complete sentence because it lacks a conjugated verb, no word would have a "verb ending" (except maybe for an infinitive _-i_), I guess.